# Syntax error on data-target in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am completely new to ReactJS and I 'm working on existing app, there I found some error in the line

```
<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="'#'+{providers.TICKET_NUMBER}">
{providers.TICKET_NUMBER} </span>
```

The error displaying is `"jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#'+{providers.TICKET_NUMBER}`
Kindly please help,if possible. Excuse mistakes,If any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the expression in a pair of `{}`

```
 data-target={"#" + providers.TICKET_NUMBER}>
```